# How to delete a Cloudflare page that builds from my github repo?

Tags: github, cloudflare

I used Clouflare Pages before I learn how to deploy my static webapps to Firebase. Now I am stack because there is no way to remove it from internet. The project website is still there, it has no domain name attached to it. I am using Firebase instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the project? You can find it by going to the Setting tab in your project, then scroll down.